# How to get list of strings from string using a pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I know the question sound's a bit weird. Let me explain the situation:

I have an undefined text that looks like this:

`Lorem {placeholder1} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. {placeholder2} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, {placeholder3} nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo`

As you may notice, there are some placeholders inside the text: `{PlaceholderX}`. The only thing I know is that a placeholder is surrounded by `{}`. I dont know what's between them.

Now i'm looking for the best way to get a list of all strings surrounded by {} out of my text.

Or, to make it more general, is there a method where I can provide some kind of pattern like `{*}` and get back all fitting words as strings?

Comment: Put a REGEX tag on this.  I don't know REGEX well enough to give you the REGEX but REGEX will do that.  I guess I have the authority to tag.  I added regex.

Comment: hmmmm, pattern matching in a natural language.  This sounds like a job for Regex!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for regular expressions, in this case you need to make use of [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=\{)(.*)(?=\})
```

The .* means it will find any non-space character between the braces

[Here is a C# tutorial on how this can be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Here is an example that shows how to pull out each item](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match)

I have adapted it for your example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // First we see the input string.
    string input = "Lorem {placeholder} ipsum {placeholder2} ...";

    // Here we call Regex.Match.
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\{)(.*)(?=\})",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
        foreach(var matchgroup in match.Groups)
            Console.WriteLine(matchgroup.Value);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression. Something like this:

```
string pattern = @"Your text with {placeholders} in it"
string[] placeholders = regex.Matches(input, @"\{\w+\}");
```

Comment: This will give you the {} also. The OP asked for only values surrounded by the {}

Comment: @JustinPihony yeah, you are right. i missed that. I won't bother updating it as you have already covered it in more depth in your answer. (So i +1'd you)

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\{[^\}]+\}");
string[] matches = regex.Matches(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, just paste in any regular expression from an answer posted. There are many possibilities depending on how the placeholders are formatted.

```
String s = "Lorem {placeholder1} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. {placeholder2} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, {placeholder3} nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo";
Regex r = new Regex("{[a-zA-Z0-9]+}"); // Or any other regex found in one of the answers.
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
foreach (Match m in mc) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Make sure you're using

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "Lorem {placeholder1} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. {placeholder2} Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, {placeholder3} nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"{\w*}");
var temp= regex.Matches(s);
foreach(var item in temp)
{
     string key = item.ToString().Trim('{').Trim('}');
     Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lazy-plus regex pattern. This will work:

```
var txt =
    @"Lorem {placeholder1} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. {placeholder2} Cum sociis 
    natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, {placeholder3} nascetur 
    ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium 
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo";

// need to do a lazy plus match...
var pattern = @"\{.+?\}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(txt, pattern);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

The output will be

```
{placeholder1}
{placeholder2}
{placeholder3}
```

This being said, have you looked into [NVelocity](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html)?